# Inserting a Space in to a Text String Preparing a File Directory

Tags: vba, excel

I've prepared a code that reads cells within a sheet and uses those cells to determine the directory to follow to open the necessary file.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
"Q:\Accounts Department\JM Period End ADI\1516\Stats\Period 0" & Range("C3").Value & _
"\Eng PERIOD Reports SOUTH P" & Range("C3").Value & Range("C6").Value & " 15 16.xls"
```

What I want this to return is `"Q:\Accounts Department\JM Period End ADI\1516\Stats\Period 01\Eng PERIOD Reports South P1 Jul 15 16.xls"`.

But rather than this, it's returning `"Q:\Accounts Department\JM Period End ADI\1516\Stats\Period 01\Eng PERIOD Reports South P1Jul 15 16.xls"` (*notice the lack of a space between* `P1Jul` *at the end*).

Can anyone please assist in getting a space in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Range("C3").Value & Range("C6").Value
```

to

```
Range("C3").Value & " " & Range("C6").Value
```

I am assuming that `Range("C3").Value` is `1` and `Range("C6").Value` is `Jul`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I see what was needed now, I had tried the double " " but did not add the & after it, only before. That's great though, thanks for your help.